# How would you use LESS without Node.js on a symfony2+Assetic project

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

Don't get me wrong. I know we had `lessc` and even other compilers in php (I'm talking about [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)) and others.

But!  You know, I really like [less.js way to work](http://markup.io/v/58ctep9s20h7).

What I mean...

- point to your less file
- Point to the javascript
- work

When you are done

- Get the `localStorage` version from the browser
- Put it into a CSS file.

Have you ever thought of a way to do something similar?

Comment: Why asking your browser to do the work if you can get it directly server side? Anyway, there is still the rhino way if you don't like node: http://caffeinelab.net/2011/07/18/lesscss-and-rhino/ .

Comment: If you **really** want to get the css from a browser, you could imagine writing a phantomjs script that gets the content of less's LocalStorage and put it in a static file only in prod environment.

Comment: CSS is meant to be static.  What I mean is that one file, cached by the browser (part of http 1.1 spec).    --   The application can provide different context sensitive new css that adds up to the base of the CSS. but this is out of this conversation. :)   My point is that at the end of the dev, you use the localStorage'd version (that is one liner compressed) to your stylesheet.  If you have many contexts for the application, use different file.less entry points.  In prod should be only static css

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure i understand the question.  I use sass with Symfony-2.  Works fine.  Sometimes I use the --watch option for automatic updates.  Sometimes I use the Assetic scss filter.  Never used less but there is a filter for it.

I always just checkin the final css file so I don't need to fool with generating one during deployment.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid, using a "watch"-er.   My current setup is with less.min.js  and I use a condition. I'll document about it later.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post about using lessphp with assetic: (so no nodejs needed)

for Symfony2.1: https://gist.github.com/3049271
for Symfony2.0: https://gist.github.com/1844433

The seps:

Add the following lines of code to the composer.json file:

```
"leafo/lessphp": "*"
```

Run composer install
The best approach is to add file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php to config.yml file:

```
#...
assetic:
    #...
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

and then in your template you can use the less like this:

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/public/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less*' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```